# $E($bishop moves$) = E($knight moves$)$ when each square on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is blocked with probability $p$

Tags: probability, expected-value, chessboard

I came across this probability problem in a placement exam a few days ago , and i was not able to solve it. so, i am trying to solve it since then but i couldn't come up with a solution so please provide the solution and have fun solving it.

**Problem Statement** : We have an infinite chessboard with a bishop and knight on the same row. A massive meteor storm erupted, landing a meteor in each square of the chessboard with probability $p$ randomly and independently. The bishop and knight were not damaged, although their mobility may have been hampered by the meteors. For what value of $p$ is the expected number of valid squares to which the bishop may advance(in a single move) equal to the expected number of squares to which the knight can travel (in a single move)?
Note that both the knight and bishop can't move to a square stuck with a meteor and the bishop can't move past a cell stuck with a meteor. For example if the bishop is on the cell (3,3) and the meteor strikes (5,5), then it can't move to (5,5),(6,6),(7,7) or any other cell beyond it after one move from (3,3)

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how a knight moves? Can you calculate the expected number of possible moves for either piece?

Comment: Without the meteors the Knight can move to 8 positions so i need to find the expectation of number of squares which are not blocked after the meteor shower to me it seems like a binomial distribution where probability of getting blocked is 'p' and not blocked is say, 'q' and the expectation of binomial should be 8q = 8(1-p), correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That sounds right to me!

Comment: Now i am not sure how to approach for the bishop.

Comment: Linearity of expectation helps. Can you find the probability that a given square is reachable by the bishop?

Comment: Okay so if i want to find if the nth diagonal square from bishop is reachable then all n squares should not be blocked so that would be (1-p)^n.

Comment: You mention both being on the same row, but in fact you just want both of them not to intervene (imagine one being on $(1,1)$ and the other on $(5,4)$ that would also be ok. Am I right?

Comment: yes i think the same row condition was given only to remove the possibility of knight being on one of the diagonals of bishop or bishop being on a position where the knight can move.so, both possibilities are removed.

Comment: The expected value of the number of possible moves post-meteor shower for the knight, $E(M_k) = 0\cdot p^4 + 1 \cdot \times ^4C_1 \times p^3q + 2\cdot \times ^4C_2 \times p^2q^2 + 3 \times ^4C_3 \times pq^3 + 4 \cdot q^4$. Assuming $q = 1 - p$    

The expected value of the number of possible moves post-meteor shower for the bishop, the calculation is too complicated for me to handle. I got only so far as $0$ moves ($0 \times p^4$) and $1$ move ($1 \times ^4C_1 \times p^3q$).   

P.S. On an *infinite* chessboard, the probability $p \to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be the number of legal moves of the bishop and knight respectively. Consider the $4$ diagonal rays of valid moves of the bishop. For $i=1,2,3,4$ and $j\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, let $A_{ij}$ be $1$ if the $j$th square of the $i$th diagonal is accessible to the bishop, and $0$ otherwise. Then by symmetry we have, for all $i=1,2,3,4$ and all $j\in\mathbb{Z}_+$,

$$A_{ij} =^dA_{1j},$$

where the "$=^d$" indicates "equal in distribution". Now, $A_{1j}\sim$Bernoulli$((1-p)^j)$, so

$$E(X) = 4\sum_{j=1}^\infty E(A_{1j}) = 4\sum_{j=1}^\infty (1-p)^j = 4(1-p)/p.$$

On the other hand, $E(Y) = 8(1-p)$, so we find $p=1$ or $p=1/2$ as solutions.

Comment: As a small improvement you could directly derive the expectation of $X$ as 4 times the expectation of a random variable with geometric distribution.

Comment: @Trailblazer ah yes, that would be cleaner. The geometric random variable would correspond to the first square that is blocked on a diagonal.